# Extract all the traffic corresponding to a request with a parameter

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, for

For each line of `access.log` with the pattern `/mypattern`:

```
www.example.com:80 192.0.2.17 - - [29/Sep/2017:13:49:02 +0200] "GET /mypattern?foo=bar&iptosearch=198.51.100.5
```

I would like to extract the `iptosearch` parameter, and show all the lines of `access.log` that have this IP **and** which contains `blah`. Example:

```
 [29/Sep/2017:13:49:02 +0200] "GET /mypattern?foo=bar&iptosearch=198.51.100.5: 
    www.example3.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
    www.example2.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [25/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
    www.example7.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [12/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /index.htm?i=blah" ...

 [27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /mypattern?iptosearch=203.0.113.2&foo2=bar5: 
    www.example32.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [15/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
    www.example215.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [14/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
```

I am trying to do it with:

```
grep -f <(grep -o 'mypattern.*iptosearch=(.*)' access.log) access.log |grep blah
```

but:

- it probably won't be sorted like in my example before: with a header, and the list below corresponding to the relevant `iptosearch`
- the header in my example (`[29/Sep/2017:13:49:02 +0200] "GET /test?foo=bar&iptosearch=198.51.100.5:`) won't be displayed because it doesn't contain `blah`

**How to do this, to have the display like before?** Should one use a loop in such a case, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended **bash** + **grep** + **awk** approach:

Sample `access.log` content:

```
www.example3.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
www.example2.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [25/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
[29/Sep/2017:13:49:02 +0200] "GET /mypattern?foo=bar&iptosearch=198.51.100.5: 
www.example7.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [12/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /index.htm?i=blah" ...
www.example32.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [15/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
[27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /mypattern?iptosearch=203.0.113.2&foo2=bar5: 
www.example215.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [14/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
```

---

The job:

```
grep '/mypattern' access.log | while read -r l; do 
    if [[ $l =~ iptosearch=(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) ]]; then 
        echo "$l"
        awk -v ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" '$0~ip && /blah/;END{ print "" }' access.log
    fi
done
```

---

The output:

```
[29/Sep/2017:13:49:02 +0200] "GET /mypattern?foo=bar&iptosearch=198.51.100.5:
www.example3.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
www.example2.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [25/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
www.example7.com:80 198.51.100.5 - - [12/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /index.htm?i=blah" ...

[27/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /mypattern?iptosearch=203.0.113.2&foo2=bar5:
www.example32.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [15/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /hello/blah" ...
www.example215.com:80 203.0.113.2 - - [14/Sep/2017:00:00:00 +0200] "GET /blah.html" ...
```

---

Details:

- `while read -r l ...` - iterating over lines containing `/mypattern`, returned by `grep` command
- `[[ $l =~ iptosearch=(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+) ]]` - match each line `$l` against regular expression `iptosearch=(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)`. 
  `BASH_REMATCH` is an array variable whose members are assigned by the ‘`=~`’ binary operator to the `[[` conditional command. The element with index `0` is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression. The element with index `n` is the portion of the string matching the `n`th parenthesized subexpression `(...)`. This variable is read-only.
- `-v ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` - passing in the variable `ip` into *awk* script
- `$0~ip && /blah/` - output only lines containing the current `ip` value and keyword `blah`

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a few explanations about the if =~ and the awk -v / base rematch ?

Comment: @Basj, welcome, see my details

Comment: Thanks a lot! A last one: why $0~ip and not $ip ?

Comment: @Basj, awk is not bash. The variables are accessed by their names without `$`

Comment: Yes but why $0~ ?

Comment: @Basj, `ip` can not be evaluated itself as a regular expression in standalone, but it would be considered as regex pattern in "regex test" expression `$0~ip` which means: the entire line `$0` is tested on matching against the pattern `ip`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/blah/ && $2 == "198.51.100.5" { print }' access.log
```

Search for all lines with the text blah within. If the second space delimited is field is also "198.51.100.5", print the line.