# Capture groups with awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep

I'd like to loop over each pattern found and have access to the different capture groups inside the loop, possibly with `grep` or `awk` (I'd like to stick with them if possible to avoid to learn a 3rd one, but if really necessary, I'll learn another one!)

Does something like:

```
awk-or-grep -E '(blah(.*)hello=(.*))' sampletext | while read -r l; do 
    echo $0             #1st capture group
    echo $1             #2nd catpure group
    dosomethingwith $2  #3rd capture group
done
```

exist?

---

Sample text:

```
blah12687hello=123
nothingthatmatches
blah3211hello=123456
blah15butnottheotherpattern
```

With the loop mentioned before, it should output:

```
blah12687hello=123
12687
<it should run the command dosomethingwith 123>
blah3211hello=123456
3211
<it should run the command dosomethingwith 123456>
```

Comment: The `bash` shell itself provides one, why wouldn't you use it? And capture groups of `Awk/grep` are close constrained in a sense it will not be available in the shell context by only within their own. Do you have a sample of text (or) file content to better explain your question?

Comment: @Inian the question comes from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396034/59989) where I was wondering if it's possible to have the two first lines of "The job" condensed into one single `awk` or `grep` and let them capture the groups...  Can you show an example of what you mean with bash only? (I updated with a sample example).

Comment: `blah` and `hello=` patterns are always fixed patterns? if yes, it's easy job for `awk` or even `sed` otherwise solution will be a bit complex

Comment: @αғsнιη Yes, fixed patterns.

Comment: @Inian I added a sample and required output (the requirements are detailed in the loop before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bash` shell by itself provides a way to do regular expression matching process the captured groups as conveniently needed.

The `=~` operator within a double brackets test expression, `[[` with the match string on the left side of the operator and  regular expression as the right operand.

```
if [[ "$str" =~ $re ]]; then
```

If the expression matches the string, the matched part of the string is stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array which can be looped over to access the individual captured groups. The exit status is `0` if the regexp matches, `1` if it doesn't, and `2` if the expression is invalid.

---

As far as your example is concerned, assuming you have the input lines stored in an array and the words `blah` and `hello` are fixed patterns

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exampleStr=('blah12687hello=123' 'nothingthatmatches' 'blah3211hello=123456' 'blah15butnottheotherpattern')

re='blah([[:digit:]]+)hello=([[:digit:]]+)'

for str in "${exampleStr[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$str" =~ $re ]]; then
       for group in "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do
           printf "%s\n" "$group"
       done
    else
       printf "No match \n"
    fi
done
```

As you can see in the code above, once we match the regex to be true we can loop over the `BASH_REMATCH` array to print each of the captured group. The overall script output would be something like

```
blah12687hello=123     # Value of BASH_REMATCH[0]
12687                  # Value of BASH_REMATCH[1]
123                    # Value of BASH_REMATCH[2]
Regex not matches.
blah3211hello=123456
3211
123456
Regex not matches.
```

As you can see the `BASH_REMATCH[0]` always contains the part of the string that was successfully matched by the regex, and the individual captured groups can be accessed from index `1` onward. You can write custom logic to process each of the captured group which is what you originally intended to do.

---

If you are interested in reading a file input, just use a `while` loop with input re-direction on the file to be processed

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $re ]]; then
       for group in "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do
           printf "%s\n" "$group"
       done
    else
       printf "No match \n"
    fi
done < inputFile.txt
```